# Basic visual studio c++ 2015 help mfc classes?

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2012, mfc, addition

I'm trying to get started with visual c++ by looking at some open source code and following some tutorials.  I'm looking at the code and trying to figure out where parts are that I could modify but it's all just a bunch of confusing mess to me at this point for some very large open source and tutorial programs I'm looking at.  I can't find the code that contains information about a specific variable or input for instance that I would like to try to understand better.

One of the things you see in beginner tutorials is that you can bring up the resource visual part of the application.  Most tutorials start with drawing out the gui interface.  The thing that they do to bring them to the coding area is just double clicking on the element.  When I do this with my example source files though it just brings up the MFC add Class wizard, it doesn't take me to the code?  I've tried researching what that is and gotten nowhere.  Can someone explain to me why it doesn't take me to the relevant code what the mfc class wizard is, and how to find the parts of code that spcifically having to do with the particular input box/slider/dropdown ect easily?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Skip using the IDE, until you understand Windows programming. Charles Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](http://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X) is mandatory reading for any Windows programmer. If you decide to use MFC, get a copy of Jeff Prosise' [Programming Windows with MFC, Second Edition](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1572316950), but MFC is not required (nor the only option) to write Windows applications.

Comment: Alright thanks. I'm getting those.  Are they specifically about visual c++ though, cause I'm writing a program that uses a specific library that only exists in visual c++....

Comment: Hmm I got the 6th edition of that one, that's about c#..which isn't going to be much use to me I think.

Comment: Found some stuff here...so is the mfc like...what a different way to structure a program or something?  So the examples I have I need to convert to mfc somehow?  I really dont get this mfc stuff at all. sigh http://www.functionx.com/visualc/classes/slider1.htm

Comment: I found a sort of explination, although not really how to use it here: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/faq-board/9132-faq-what-mfc.html   But that still doesn't explain why it keeps brining it up when I click on a control and the gui isn't linked to the code in the existing programs.   Is there just a way to turn this mfc stuff off and have it go to the code?